# websharper access to rpc from another site (SPA)

Tags: single-page-application, rpc, websharper

I've got a client-server (with transpiled js and rpc calls to server) application with websharper, and it runs perfectly fine.

Now I need a single javascript file for another site (a WordPress app) and from this script, I'd like to access to everything public (non protected rpc) I made in my former client-server application.

The ideal would be to be able to use the websharper SPA template and "link" to the client-server project.

I've got two problems:
- First, rpc signature are encoded with a hash which seems to be local to the app (no simple way to reproduct this hash outside it)
- Second, apparently there is no way to actually link the generated dll from the client-server app into the new SPA template and use the exported rpc method signatures for the SPA.

Am I missing something, how to make this work ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing your client-server application from your SPA should work just fine; you just need to make sure that it points to the right URL by calling the following somewhere in your SPA:

```
WebSharper.Remoting.EndPoint <- "http://your-client-server-application's-url"
```

Comment: Ok, that's a start.
Now my problem is that I can't seem to trigger the CORS header in the website.
I added
`WebSharper.Web.Remoting.AddAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:51715")`
the main `[<Website>]` but it doesn't trigger any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: I just tried, added the AllowedOrigin as you just did, and I got the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response and the RPC went through. `http://localhost:5‌​1715` is your SPA's URL, right? (also, how is your server app hosted: basic, Owin or Suave?)

Comment: It works only if I add `DisableCsrfProtection`
I use the basic client-server container template (the one with asp.net)
Now is there a way to reenable Csrf or is it by design ?